# Gradle running tests sequentially

Tags: android, gradle

I saw some documentation regarding executing tests in a specific order and while I have found [Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) for running TestNG tests, this didn't work for doing android tests.

I am aware of the `-Dtest.single=SomeTestClass` but it requires a task to take in that argument.

If someone could point me in the right direction for just running single tests, I'm sure I could figure out making a task to run them sequentially. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just curious, why is it required to perform tests in particular order? Does it not contradict to the very idea of unit-testing?

Comment: @akhikhl It's not so much running the tests sequentially, it's just about running a certain set of tests without having separate packages just for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you are looking for a way to run specific tests, and not others. Using TestNG you can achieve this by using the ['group'](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) option inside the @Test.

You also need to tell gradle about the groups you want/do not want to run. Gradle's [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_grouping) has an example of how to do this.

I think you are looking for the following. **I haven't tested this myself, it was just pulled from documentation.**

If you had 3 different groups (from the documentation)

```
public class Test1 {
  @Test(groups = { "misctest", "checkintest" })
  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  @Test(groups = {"functest", "checkintest"} )
  public void testMethod2() {
  }

  @Test(groups = { "functest" })
  public void testMethod3() {
  }
}
```

you could have three gradle tasks

```
task testFunc(type: Test) {
    useTestNG {
        includeGroups 'functest'
    }
}

task testMisc(type: Test) {
    useTestNG {
        includeGroups 'misctest'
    }
}

task testCheckInTest(type: Test) {
    useTestNG {
        includeGroups 'checkintest'
    }
}
```

Each of the three tasks would be able to run the tests that you wanted / needed to run.